# Generate TLS certificates for Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, pycharm, ssl-certificate, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Within **PyCharm** I am trying to connect to the Docker daemon using the API url. However it will not connect without a valid certificate.

I have **Docker Desktop for Windows** installed and within the Hyper-V Manager the MobyLinuxVM is running. I can create images etc. with no problems using the `docker` commands withing PowerShell, so I know it's running correctly and the issue is the communication with PyCharm.

I would try regenerating the certificates using `docker-machine regenerate-certs` however it appears MobyLinuxVM created by Docker for Windows is independent of the `docker-machine` commands.

How can I (re-)generate the certificates required to connect to the docker daemon over TLS?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) is a doc on SSL for the daemon.  Ping if you're having problems or the doc doesn't cover your case and I can dig in with you :)